# Is it possible to unit test service contracts without having to run the actual service?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, testing, service, servicecontract

I work on an application that uses a WCF service (which in fact is a service-client solution).

The problem that came up was that when we did a bit of refactoring, it turned out that some of the service contracts became invalid. This was not shown until the service and application were running.

Now, I would like to write test cases that simply tests the service contracts such that when they missmatch the test cases fail. Is this possible to do without having to run the actual service?

That is, can I some how simulate the service part and call the client calls at the same time in the test case?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is not possible, because there are very much traps which can happen if you execute functions over the net.

E.g. timeouts, connection failures, authorization problems and so on.

Write offline unit tests for the code in the methods itself should be possible, but this is IMHO just one little part of the work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just speaking my mind here. Would .Net Reflection solve your problem? I mean, inspect the binaries that contain the service(s) contracts that you want to verify.